# Unable to transfer local file wsl ubuntu terminal to remote server using windows subsystem

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux, scp

I have a file called `test1.zip` in `/mnt/c/Users/test/` folder of my local laptop [in which ubuntu windows subsystem for linux is installed]. Local ubuntu terminal WSL name is `lauda`

Now, I would like to transfer this zip file called `test1.zip` to my remote server named `stuff`.

**PLEASE NOTE THAT ALL COMMANDS ARE TRIED FROM MY LOCAL LAPTOP WSL SCREEN [ubuntu screen]**

So, I tried the below command from my WSL [local laptop ubuntu WSL terminal]

```
scp user1@lauda:/mnt/c/Users/test/test1.zip user1@stuff:/home/test/codes/test1
```

and got the error `ssh: Could not resolve hostname lauda: Name or service not known`

So I tried the below [replacing the `lauda` local laptop ubuntu terminal hostname with its IP]

```
scp user1@172.xx.xxx.xxx:/mnt/c/Users/test/test1.zip user1@stuff:/home/test/codes/test1
```

this resulted in error as `ssh: connect to host 172.xx.xxx.xxx port 22: Connection refused`

Now I tried the same command as above but in opposite way as shown below

```
scp user1@stuff:/home/test/codes/ user1@lauda:/mnt/c/Users/test/test1.zip
```

and got the below error

`ssh: Could not resolve hostname lauda: Temporary failure in name resolution`

Later, I tried with IP address

```
 scp user1@stuff:/home/test/codes/ user1@172.xx.xxx.xxx:/mnt/c/Users/test/test1.zip
```

And I got the below error

`ssh: connect to host 172.xx.xxx.xxx port 22: No route to host lost connection`

Later, I tried the below commands as well

```
scp /mnt/c/Users/test/test1.zip user1@stuff:/home/test/codes/
```

and got an error `scp: /home/test/codes/test1.zip: Permission denied`

So, I again tried like below

```
scp user1@stuff:/home/test/codes/ /mnt/c/Users/test/test1.zip
```

and got an error `scp: /home/test/codes: not a regular file`

**PLEASE NOTE THAT ALL COMMANDS ARE TRIED FROM MY LOCAL LAPTOP WSL SCREEN [ubuntu screen]**

How can I transfer local files/folders from my local ubuntu WSL terminal to remote server?

Comment: For your knowledge on the failed attempts:

1) and 2) failed because for the local file in the `scp` command you shouldn't provide a hostname (and mounted drivers such as the `C` drive in WSL count as local) 

3),4) Fails similarly and because it should be `scp from to`

5) was the closest to correct and explained in the answer below

6) Fails similarly to 5) as well as being reversed `scp to from` instead of `scp from to`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scp /mnt/c/Users/test/test1.zip user1@stuff:/home/test/codes/` is the closest attempt to working. The error you get could be due to one of two reasons:

Firstly `user1` does not have permissions to write to `/home/test` on `stuff` - makes sense as usually only the `test` user would be able to write there. (Note that the `test` user on your WSL instance is not the same profile the `test` user on the remote.)

Secondly the `/home/test/codes/` folder may not even exist yet.

Instead (if you know `test`'s password) copy as the `test` user :

```
scp /mnt/c/Users/test/test1.zip test@stuff:/home/test/codes/
```

Or copy to `user1`'s home directory (after ensuring you have created `/home/user1/codes/`

```
scp /mnt/c/Users/test/test1.zip user1@stuff:/home/user1/codes/
```

Comment: hi, thanks. upvoted. But still it doesn't work. can help me please. I have the password but still it throws error. Should I try in local wsl or remote server

Comment: Which password? For `test` on the remote server? Becausde that is not the same as `test` on your WSL instance necessarily

Comment: for this command, `scp /mnt/c/Users/test/test1.zip user1@stuff:/home/test/codes/`, I know the `user1` password...

Comment: and `test` is a folder and not user

Comment: Okay, I mean on `local laptop side, test` is a user` but on remote server, `test` is a folder

Comment: Traditionally on linux computers folders `/home/xxxx` are folders belonging to a user named `xxxx`. Its not enforced, but that's true 99.9% of the time. So as `user1` you should place anything you want in a folder named `/home/user1`

Comment: But one additional question. Even if permission denied to write, I tried with Sudo. But still it doesn't work. Do you know why.. Of course, after changing folder it worked